# Embed a var in a backgroundImage url in a reactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need to load an URL that contains an ID. That URL is used on a Div to show a background Image. I am pretty new to reactJS and I can't seem to get the syntaxe right.

```
  <div
    className="image"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: "url("+"https://admin.cliiic.com/api/adThumb/"+{result.id.raw}+")",
    }}
  />
```

That gives me the following error

```
/src/ResultView.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:81)

   8 |         className="image"
   9 |         style={{
> 10 |           backgroundImage: "url("+"https://admin.cliiic.com/api/adThumb/"+{result.id.raw}+")",                                                                     ^
  11 |         }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually JS tries to parse

```
+{result.id.raw}+")",
//   ^^^^^ . causes the syntax error, since object key must not contain a dot
```

as an object, that's why you are getting this syntax error.
I would suggest you to use `string literal` instead:

```
backgroundImage: `url(https://admin.cliiic.com/api/adThumb/${result.id.raw})`,
```

...**or** just remove the curly brackets.

Comment: Worked great thx! This will get handy a few times I am sure ^^